# Unable to extract a value from a JSON response to use as an enviroment variable in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

Pre Request:

```
//Create random number
let randomNum = 
        Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
            .toString(16)
            .substring(1);

//Set Random # as the Random ID       
pm.environment.set("randomNum", randomNum);
```

Body:

```
{   
    "AccountNumber": "AA{{randomNum}}",
            "Name": "AA {{randomNum}}",
            "Reference": "AA 01",
            "VatCodeId": 1,
              "UserCreated": "James"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "Id": 18,
    "AccountNumber": "AA7e40",
    "Name": "AA 7e40",
    "Reference": "AA 01",
    "VatCodeId": 1,
    "DateCreated": "2022-01-27T09:53:43.6734454+00:00",
    "UserCreated": "James"
}
```

Note: The Id field is being created when a 200 response is being returned, this is unique to the DB and increments by 1 for every new account created.

I am trying to extract the Id and use that as a Enviroment variable so it can be chained (for deletion of accounts). The Test script is:

```
var accountUniqueId = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set("accountId", json.result.data.Id);
```

Though I have tried variations of it such as:

```
var accountUniqueId = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("accountId", jsonData.Id);
var accountUniqueId = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("accountId", jsonData.response.Id);
```

The response in the Test is showing as:
There was an error in evaluating the test script:  ReferenceError: json is not defined

The Enviroment Variable is being created with a current value of:
[object Object].

Comment: You were assigning the full response to a variable `accountUniqueId` but then not using that and using `jsonData.Id` instead. `accountUniqueId.Id` would have worked.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
let jsonData= pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("accountId", jsonData.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks very much Christian. I should remove the response in the enviroment set for future test.
var accountUniqueId = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("accountId", jsonData.response.Id);

Comment: Or just that > `pm.environment.set("accountId", pm.response.json().Id);` :D